# Fibonacci numbers notation

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

$F_{i}$ denotes the $i^{th}$ Fibonacci number, but what does it mean when there are 2 subscripts, $F_{ij}$?

Context: show that $F_{i}$|$F_{ij}$ (where $i$ and $j$ are positive integers)

Thanks

Comment: I haven't seen the two subscripts in a Fibonacci context before. Can you show us the context that you found it in?

Comment: Sure, I will add it in the question

Comment: It’s just ordinary multiplication: $ij$ in the second subscript is the product of $i$ and $j$.

Comment: Written in a another way: if $m \mid n$ then $F_m \mid F_n$.